# Automatically Submit the form in 20 sec

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to automatically submit this form 20 sec, but something is wrong and is not working, i dont have any error messages and i am using this as a starting point to get the username and password from a URL and substitute this into respective fields in login and submit

```html
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-signin"
  id="form" name="{$form_name}" action="{$form_action}" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm('{$form_objectRequiredFields}');">
  <input type="hidden" class="notValidateThisFields" name="__notValidateThisFields__" id="__notValidateThisFields__" value="{$form_objectRequiredFields}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="DynaformRequiredFields" id="DynaformRequiredFields" value="{$form_objectRequiredFields}" />
  {$form.BROWSER_TIME_ZONE_OFFSET}
    <div style="display: none;"> {$form.USR_PASSWORD}</div>
    <fieldset>
      <label class="panel-login">
        <div class="login_result"></div>
      </label>
      {$form.USR_USERNAME}
      {$form.USR_PASSWORD_MASK}
      {$form.USER_LANG}
      {$form.URL}
      {$form.FAILED_LOGINS}

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label class="panel-login">
            <div class="login_result"></div>
        </label>
        <br>
        {$form.BSUBMIT}
        {$form.FORGOT_PASWORD_LINK}

    </fieldset>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      {$form.JS}
    </script>
 <script>
 window.onload=function() {literal}{{/literal}
  var x = 20;
  var y = document.getElementById("timer");
  
 
  setInterval(function(){literal}{{/literal}
   if( x<=21 && x>=1)
  {literal} { {/literal}
   x--;
   y.innerHTML= ''+x+''; 
   
   if(x==1)
   {literal}{{/literal}
    x=21;
   {literal}} {/literal}
  {literal}} {/literal}
  
  {literal}}{/literal}, 1000);
  
 

    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {literal}{{/literal} submitform(); {literal}}{/literal}, 20000);

 
 function submitform()
 {literal} { {/literal}
  alert('Form is submitting.....');
     document.getElementById("form").submit();
  
 {literal} } {/literal}
 </script>
</form>
<script src="/lib/pmdynaform/libs/respondjs/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/pmdynaform/libs/html5shiv/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {literal}{{/literal} dynaformSetFocus();}catch(e){literal}{{/literal}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

```
 button.onclick=function(){ 
        button.setTimeout(function() { document.formId.submit(); }, 20000);
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function(){  // document.ready function...
   setTimeout(function(){
      $('formId').submit();
    }, 20000);    // In milliseconds - 20 seconds is given here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use window.setTimeout() to execute a function based on milliseconds.

```
window.setTimeout(submitform, 20000);
```

function submitform will execute after 20000ms